# Displaying Filters in search

Tags: usability, search, selection

I have business roles as a group of check boxes and based on selection of this group system will show Business activity.

**Is there any alternate way to show Business Activity on selection of Business Roles?**

I have thought to show a button with some label "Apply", after selecting Business roles user will press "Apply" button to see Business Activity.

Please see below screenshot for example.

[image]

Comment: Looking at this design, my first thought was that I'd just press search after marking a checkbox. I guess if apply is a separate action, the search query would not be using my filter criteria if I just hit 'search'? That would seem odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning filters in general, I would say that insering a little bar showing the user what filters are on (and where he can delete some) is a great way to give him multiples possibilities to do what he wants.

Also, in your case, I don't think the "apply" bouton is clear enough. I've not even seen it  in my first 5 seconds of looking at your design.
I would probably use a "Auto-apply" feature on those filters. The user choose what he wants, the page change accordingly.
This works perfectly if your category are not complex (I mean, if you're working in a environment where you have to choose 10+ filters, auto-apply may not be good, still you should try it out).
Why using Auto-Apply? For the sake of feedback. When a user perform an action, you have to give him real feedback about how his actions are shaping the UI. One example could also be hilighting your "Apply" button when something change and changing the text to "Apply new filters". So the user know that he putted some filters on it.

Hope this will help,
Cheers.